# Disable Checkbox by comparing dates

Tags: jquery

I am working on a project and need some help. I want to do something like this
All the checkbox are having same class and their data is extracted from database.
If i check checkbox 1 then checkbox 2 should get disabled as date of checkbox2 is lying in the duration of dates of checkbox 1. Simillarly when checkbox 2 is checked then checbox1 and checkbox 3 should get disabled because of dates. This will happen with a large number of checkboxes.

1. This is checkbox 1 (2015-03-02 to 2015-03-09)
2. This is checkbox 2(2015-03-05 to 2015-03-15)
3. This is checkbox 3(2015-03-13 to 2015-03-19)

Comment: Can you show us your failing code?

Comment: The problem is don't know from where to start i am stuck here

Comment: I have extracted checkbox data like value of checkbox from database using php. All checkboxes are having same class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I expect this will give you an idea to start

```
 $('.chkboxClass').on('click',function()
{
    if($(this).hasClass('active'))
    {
        $(this).siblings().attr("disabled", false);
        $(this).removeClass('active');
        return;
    }
    $(this).addClass('active');
    var elem = $(this).val();  // Fetching the selected checkbox value
    var selectedDateSplit = elem.split('to');
    var selectedEndDate = new Date(selectedDateSplit[1].trim());  
    var allOthorCheckBox = $(this).siblings(); //Find all other checkboxes

    $(allOthorCheckBox).each(function(){ // Looping through the chckboxes
        var chkBoxValue = $(this).val();
        var chkBoxValueSplit = chkBoxValue.split('to');
        var otherCheckBoxStartDate =  new Date(chkBoxValueSplit[0].trim());
        if(selectedEndDate > otherCheckBoxStartDate) // Checking selected checkbox endDate > other chckbox start date 
        {
            $(this).attr("disabled", true);
        }
    });
```

Updated js fiddle link is added.
http://jsfiddle.net/LMKLMK/47m2ehvf/3/

Comment: Is it meet your requirement?

Comment: Your answer is really helpfull but what if i uncheck it ?i Checked your link its really helpfull. I unchecked the checkbox and other checkboxes were still disabled. I am new to jquery so can you solve that for me

Comment: Yes it is almost meeting my requirements just the uncheck option should also be there

Comment: It is not working for the second time if i check the checkbox again it doesn't work

Comment: And Script is working in Google Chrome but not in mozilla firefox

Comment: Thanks all the problems are solved except that the script is not working in firefox